# My Android App program keeps force closing

Tags: android, android-intent, android-emulator, forceclose

I do not understand why when I run it in the emulator it force closes. I made a splash screen and that comes up no problem but it won't get passed that:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
protected boolean _active = true;
protected int _splashTime = 5000;

// Called when the activity is first created.
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // thread for displaying the SplashScreen
    Thread splashTread = new Thread() 
    {
        @Override
        public void run() 
        {
            try 
            {
                int waited = 0;
                while(_active && (waited < _splashTime)) 
                {
                    sleep(100);
                    if(_active) 
                    {
                        waited += 100;
                    }
                }
            } 
            catch(InterruptedException e) 
            {
                // do nothing
            } 
            finally 
            {
                finish();
                startActivity(new Intent("com.example.textsmslock.EnableActivity"));
                stop();
            }
        }
    };
    splashTread.start();
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        _active = false;
    }
    return true;
}
}
```

after the splash screen, it is supposed to go to another activity code below:

```
public class Enable extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_enable);
   // getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_enable, menu);
    return true;
}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
public void EnableYes(View view)
{
    startActivity(new Intent("com.example.textsmslock.EnterPin"));
}
public void EnableNo(View view)
{

}

}
```

Red Logcats

```
11-17 21:04:53.504: E/Zygote(32): setreuid() failed. errno: 2
11-17 21:05:00.924: E/Zygote(32): setreuid() failed. errno: 17
11-17 21:05:02.074: E/BatteryService(58): usbOnlinePath not found
11-17 21:05:02.074: E/BatteryService(58): batteryVoltagePath not found
11-17 21:05:02.074: E/BatteryService(58): batteryTemperaturePath not found
11-17 21:05:02.094: E/SurfaceFlinger(58): Couldn't open /sys/power/wait_for_fb_sleep or /sys/power/wait_for_fb_wake
11-17 21:05:07.994: E/EventHub(58): could not get driver version for /dev/input/mouse0, Not a typewriter
11-17 21:05:07.994: E/EventHub(58): could not get driver version for /dev/input/mice, Not a typewriter
11-17 21:05:08.653: E/System(58): Failure starting core service
11-17 21:05:08.653: E/System(58): java.lang.SecurityException
11-17 21:05:08.653: E/System(58):   at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native Method)
11-17 21:05:08.653: E/System(58):   at android.os.ServiceManagerProxy.addService(ServiceManagerNative.java:146)
11-17 21:05:08.653: E/System(58):   at android.os.ServiceManager.addService(ServiceManager.java:72)
11-17 21:05:08.653: E/System(58):   at com.android.server.ServerThread.run(SystemServer.java:184)
11-17 21:05:09.293: E/SoundPool(58): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
11-17 21:05:09.304: E/SoundPool(58): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressStandard.ogg
11-17 21:05:09.304: E/SoundPool(58): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressSpacebar.ogg
11-17 21:05:09.304: E/SoundPool(58): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressDelete.ogg
11-17 21:05:09.304: E/SoundPool(58): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressReturn.ogg
11-17 21:05:35.019: E/AndroidRuntime(272): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-8
11-17 21:05:35.019: E/AndroidRuntime(272): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=this, com.example.textsmslock.Enable.class }
11-17 21:05:35.019: E/AndroidRuntime(272):  at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1408)
11-17 21:05:35.019: E/AndroidRuntime(272):  at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1378)
11-17 21:05:35.019: E/AndroidRuntime(272):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:2817)
11-17 21:05:35.019: E/AndroidRuntime(272):  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:2923)
11-17 21:05:35.019: E/AndroidRuntime(272):  at com.example.textsmslock.MainActivity$1.run(MainActivity.java:45)

**end of logcat**
```

Comment: Can you please paste the stacktrace from the logcat to see what the crash is?

Comment: [2012-11-17 21:04:46 - Emulator] could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
[2012-11-17 21:04:46 - Emulator] could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
[2012-11-17 21:04:46 - Emulator] could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
[2012-11-17 21:04:46 - Emulator] could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
[2012-11-17 21:04:46 - Emulator] could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
[2012-11-17 21:04:46 - Emulator] could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
[2012-11-17 21:04:46 - Emulator] could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
[2012-11-17 21:04:46 - Emulator] could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB

Comment: I can't tell if this is your crash. You need to post the full stack trace. Usually you'll see some exception and it will say "caused by" where you can tell if its from your app. you should see some familiar class name or a an actual trace of exactly how it got to crash. It will show the flow from your code to the final point of a crash.

Comment: well I mean I found the logcat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing the intent filter in my manifest

```
<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.textsmslock.Enable" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 0):

Without a stacktrace its hard to tell, but most likely there is no Activity called `EnableActivity`. According to your code, the Activity is called `Enable`.

A Typesafe way to do this, is to not use Strings, but instead `startActivity(new Intent(this, com.example.textsmslock.Enable.class))`

Comment: I made the changes you recommended and I got the force close. Initially, i had     startActivity(new Intent(this, com.example.textsmslock.Enable.class))

Comment: set to startActivity(new Intent(com.example.textsmslock.Enable))... how come you suggest adding .class? i'm just curious. I'm new to app programming in general

Comment: @DaJaynaeWilliams, because one of the ways you can create an Intent is to reference a class Object. So if you use a String, there's no type safety in that; meaning you'll only see a crash at runtime. Whereas if you use the class object, you'll get a compile-time error if there's no such class. Note though that it will still crash at runtime if you haven't declared the Enable activity in your manifest.

Comment: Or maybe you haven't included the activity in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

Comment: Okay I understand this is how enable is in my manifest            <activity
            android:name=".Enable"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_enable" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.example.textsmslock.MainActivity" />
        </activity>

Comment: I'll try to write an answer, wait a sec.

Answer (score 0):

First, I think you're starting the second `Activity` wrong. In your `MainActivity`, you have this:

```
startActivity(new Intent("com.example.textsmslock.EnableActivity"));
```

When you should have something like this:

```
startActivity(new Intent(this, Enable.class));
```

Second, this is how `Enable` may look like in your manifest. You don't really have to indicate the parent activity with the `meta-data` tags:

```
<activity android:name="com.example.textsmslock.Enable"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_enable"></activity>
```

Third, when people say "stack trace," you normally see that in Logcat printed out in red. It means there's an `Exception` or an error thrown.

Comment: Okay. Unfortunately they are kicking me out of the lab for the night. But I will try this tomorrow. Thank You so much!